# Problem with my sudo password

Tags: password

I am a new Ubuntu user.  I know my password to login on my Ubuntu laptop and from what I have read, the users own login password is also the password for any sudo commands in Terminal.  However, when I try to use this password for sudo commands, it tells me authentication failure.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you an admin user? Only admins are allowed to use `sudo`. Can you therefore please show the output of the `groups` command from your account?

Comment: perry@perry-Lenovo-B570:~$ groups
perry adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Comment: AFAIK the default message from sudo for a simple incorrect password is "Sorry, try again." - an "authentication failure" sounds like something different (such as a read-only filesystem, or misconfigured PAM). Can you give us some context here? when did this start to happen?

Comment: Okay, so your account is indeed an admin account. Can you please [edit] your question and add the *full, exact* output of e.g. `sudo id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Check if you use the sudo a  good way 
for example :

```
sudo ls
```

2) check if you are in the sudo group

```
id | grep sudo
```

3) check the log file to have more info

```
tail /var/log/auth.log
```

4) to add the user in the sudo group

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

Comment: @Perry if this answer has solved your issue, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it

Comment: Hello I have daemon issue. My python script is fine in terminal but failed in symfony framewrok. Please help me